# What should I do when git revert aborts with an error message?

Tags: git, commit, git-revert, mergetool

OK, so I'm getting an error sometimes when I try to revert a commit (with Git). All that I do is

`git revert <commit hash>`

and it gives me this message:

```
error: could not revert <commit hash> <commit message>
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
```

Does this mean that I should use `git mergetool` and resolve any conflicts? Once I do this can I add/rm and then commit, and the revert is complete?

Comment: The conflicts should appear in your code files, right? So thats where you should sort that out. When done make sure to commit whats right.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes you will have to resolve the conflicts, mark them as so with `git add` or `git rm` and `git commit`

The commit is not done yet, after the `git revert` - if you see .git/MERGE_MSG, you will see something like:

> Revert "adding revert"
>
> This reverts commit
>   c1366607f15a8384434948cb0bcbf8ece48bb460.
>
> Conflicts:
>
> revert

So once you resolved the merge and do a `git commit` you will be presented with the message from the MERGE_MSG file and you can commit and that completes the revert.

Comment: OK, thank you! Just wonderin' to make sure I was doing the correct thing :)

Comment: And what do I do if I realise that revert was not needed at all? How to "clear" the working directory?

Comment: @przemo_li: Enter `git status`  and it will give you a suggestion: `(use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)`

Comment: Use can use `git revert --continue` to complete the operation after you fix all conflicts.

Comment: Unfortunelly I cant do `git revert`. I am getting errors all the time like: "The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:". I can't even use `force`. I really have to manually delete theese files?

Answer (score 7):

You can use **git reset --hard**, if you want to delete all the conflicts and remove the revert you have done for which the abort error arise.

Comment: pretty sure `git reset --mixed` is a safer option.