# Git revert a commit that has some other commit depending on it

Tags: linux, git, bash

Let's say we have commit `A` and `B`, and `B` depends on `A`'s modification.
We want to revert `A`, will that be successful? Also, what would happen if a line added by 'A' is no longer present?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318777/undo-a-particular-commit-in-git

Comment: What you are asking for is simply - is it possible to revert a certain commit in git history.

Comment: ok I meant something else, dependance is indeed not correct word for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix merge conflicts in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-do-i-fix-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Answer (score 7):

`git` will report that the revert resulted in a conflict.  `git status` will show the unmerged paths.

You can [resolve the conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-do-i-fix-merge-conflicts-in-git) like any other.

---

Edit with example:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ cd foo
$ git init
$ echo "this is a line in a file" > blah
$ echo "this is a second line in a file" >> blah
$ echo "this is a third line in a file" >> blah
$ git add blah
$ git commit -m "first commit"
# edit the second line in blah
$ git commit -am "second commit"
# remove the second line from blah
$ git commit -am "third commit"
$ git revert HEAD^ #revert the second commit
error: could not revert 4862546... another change
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
$ git status
# On branch master
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
#
#   both modified:      blah
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

In the case that the first commit added the file and the second modified that file, git status will show this:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#   deleted by them:    blah
#
```

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084483/what-should-i-do-when-git-revert-aborts-with-an-error-message