# Git revert does not work as expected

Tags: git, revert

I am having trouble with the `git revert` command. I use Ubuntu 12.04 Linux and Git version 1.7.9.5.

1. I have created a brand new `b_test_repo` on my local PC, having it tracked from a remote `origin b_test_repo`.
2. I have created locally a single file (commit `A`) with two lines of text and successfully committed it only in the local `master` branch.

In order to try out `git revert` I generated 3 more commits, each of them adding one line of text.  So my `master` commit history looks like:

```
A - B - C - D
```

Where

- `A` - new file with lines 1 & 2
- `B` - one line added
- `C` - one line added
- `D` - one line added

After all these commits the file contained 5 lines:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

Then, I wanted to revert commit `B`, which would render the file without `line3`, which was added by commit `B`:

```
git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

I type:

```
git revert -n master~2
```

to revert the effect of commit `B` without committing the changes, but get the following:

```
error: could not revert 1a13ad6... Adding one line
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

I am puzzled why I am getting a conflict, i.e. why does Git have a problem figuring out what it needs to change in the file.

What am I missing here?  Please enlighten me!

Answer (score 4):

Removing that line will generate a conflict with later versions which would change the *same* line.

So as mention in "[What should I do when git revert aborts with an error message?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6084535/6309)", you need to resolve the merge, add and commit.

A simpler way to revert that commit would be an interactive rebase:

```
git rebase -i <SHA1 commit a>
```

And you drop the commit `b`.
But that is valid only if you didn't already pushed your branch to an **[upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309)**, because it does rewrite the history of commits.

If you did already push, then `git revert` is the right approach, in order to generate a new commit cancelling `b` (and push that new commit on the upstream repo).

---

In details: your example generates the following merge conflict:

```
C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\tests\18779372\r1>git lg

* 10b9953  - (HEAD)
* 07fff99  - c
* 3d888c4  - b
* 8c7155f  - a
```

(`git lg` is an [alias for a fancy `git log`](https://gist.github.com/VonC/972690#file-gitconfig-L9))

If there is a conflict, I prefer seeing both the source (theirs), destination (ours) *and* the original section as before a merge or revert:

```
git config merge.conflictstyle diff3
```

Then revert:

```
git revert -n master~2
```

That would give:

```
line1
line2
<<<<<<< HEAD
line3
line4
line5
||||||| 3d888c4... b
line3
=======
>>>>>>> parent of 3d888c4... b
```

That way, you see what `git revert` does: a **merge** between:

- the parent of commit `b` (which obviously doesn't contain `b` modification)
- and `HEAD`

The merge cannot decide what do for the *section* starting with third line:

- the section doesn't exist in `a` (the `=== >>>>` part: 'theirs' side)
- it is modified in `b` (original part between `||||` and `====`, as before `revert`, with just `line3`)
- and it is *also* modified in `HEAD` (the `<<<< ||||` part, with the addition of `line4` and `line5`, even though `line3` looks unchanged)

---

The merge conflict is even clearer if you start with commit `a` as:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

And end up with commit `d` as:

```
line1
line2
line3b
line4c
line5d
```

(commit `b` add '`d`' to line3, commit `c` adds '`c`' to line 4, commit `d` adds '`d`' to line 5)

Then a revert will give you:

```
git config merge.conflictstyle diff3
git revert -n master~2

cat afile.txt

line1
line2
<<<<<<< HEAD
line3b
line4c
line5d
||||||| 4ddccc1... b
line3b
line4
line5
=======
line3
line4
line5
>>>>>>> parent of 4ddccc1... b
```

Here the section starting at line3:

- equals `line3 -line4 -line5` in 'theirs' `=== >>>`, which is the parent of `b`, or commit `a`)
- equals `line3b-line4 -line5` in commit `b` (original section `||| ===`, before merge/revert)
- equals `line3b-line4c-line5d` in `HEAD` 'ours' `<<< |||`

Three different contents, and no way for the merge to know what to do.

Comment: Re: line1
line2
<<<<<<< HEAD
line3
line4
line5
||||||| 3d888c4... b
line3
=======
>>>>>>> parent of 3d888c4... b

That way, you see what git revert does: a merge between:

    the parent of commit b (which obviously doesn't contain b modification)
    and HEAD
-----------
Hmmm, a merge does seem to me a sound strategy of reverting commit b ?!

Comment: @BudM but... the rest of the answer should illustrate *clearly* how a merge *cannot* be automatically resolved. Can you point out to me the part of my answer that wasn't clear about that?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to say that the strategy for reverting commit b by merging the parent of commit b and HEAD does not seem logical, at least not to me.

And yes, I see who the merge attempted cannot be automatically resolved.

Comment: @BudM ok. What would be a logical strategy for revert to follow?

Comment: From what I've read about the revert git command, considering that revert b is supposed to undo the change introduced by commit b while keeping all other changes, i.e. commit c and commit d, applying commit e, which undoes the commit b changes, so that this branch history would look like a-b-c-d-e, a logical strategy would be to (1) roll backs commits d, c & b and (2) apply commits c and d again.

Comment: @BudM I agree, but this is what I see when I do revert with your scenario. Merging the parent of b seems the quickest way to "revert `b`, `c` and `d`".