# Git merge is saying I am already up to date

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-revert

I am fairly new to git and haven't ever had to deal with much more than resolving some simple conflicts up to this point. I have a project and a team member and I were working on it. I pushed a bunch of my changes(394344b) while he was working on an older copy. When he pushed his changes he somehow overwrote all my changes. Looking at the git log it looks like he called `git revert` which I guess is how he discarded my changes.

So basically, now I want to merge my changes in with the changes he made after the git revert call. Is this possible?

I created a branch with the code that was discarded

```
git checkout 394344b -b a1
```

but whenever I try to merge the two branches it doesn't look any different than the master. I'm assuming it's because all of the changes in a1 are older than the latter commits in the master.

Edit: Here is the log

```
* 1230d87 2014-09-16 | white back ground fix (HEAD, origin/master, master) [Isaac Paulsen]
* 6a44fe3 2014-09-16 | various fixe [Isaac Paulsen]
* 60f12a8 2014-09-16 | Revert 4c74c8e..b85ae54 [Isaac Paulsen]
* b85ae54 2014-09-16 | Revert "Revert 394344b..0268ad9" [Isaac Paulsen]
*   394344b 2014-09-16 | Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/crobertsbmw/HuntDay [Isaac Paulsen]
|\  
| *   4c74c8e 2014-09-16 | Merge branch 'master' of github.com:crobertsbmw/HuntDay [croberts]
| |\  
| * | e6dcb12 2014-09-16 | added permit application lookup (a1) [croberts]
* | | 3ed349c 2014-09-16 | Various changes [Isaac Paulsen]
| |/  
|/|   
* | d6a5a30 2014-09-16 | twitter icon added [Isaac Paulsen]
|/  
* 1df231b 2014-09-16 | added search by code funcitonality [croberts]
* 57119d2 2014-09-16 | Fixed the emails [croberts]
* 209679f 2014-09-09 | updated app version [Isaac Paulsen]
* 74561e9 2014-09-04 | cordova.js added [Isaac Paulsen]
* e4ff4c8 2014-09-04 | Last commit. The plugins still aren't working. we need to figure that out [croberts]
* 3ebcf60 2014-09-04 | Added cordova.js and fixed some things [croberts]
* e5157b4 2014-09-04 | Changed the alerts to navigator.alert things [croberts]
* e5998e5 2014-09-04 | Commented out the magic decoder [croberts]
* 7d2bf8f 2014-09-04 | added cordova.js [Isaac Paulsen]
* e3fd1cf 2014-09-04 | Added gitignore [croberts]
* e4b9bc9 2014-09-03 | Create README.md [crobertsbmw]
* 8f6c0c8 2014-09-03 | Still trying to fix stuff [croberts]
* 5a215c1 2014-09-03 | Trying to get the repo set up [croberts]
* 282f07f 2014-09-03 | Fixing stuff [croberts]
* d9d85b6 2014-09-03 | First commit [croberts]
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of `git log --pretty=format:"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]" --graph --date=short` instead?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accidentally remove changes in git - 'revert' isn't one of them.  Have a chat with that developer about what precisely he thought he was doing.

Presuming you don't want to force update the branches, your normal recovery path would be to 'revert' the reverts.

(note, you don't mention your branch names, adjust as needed)

```
git checkout -b fix_reverts 1230d87
git revert 60f12a8
git revert b85ae54
```

Then rebase your other work on top of that and continue on as normal.

Comment: error: could not revert 60f12a8... Revert 4c74c8e..b85ae54

Comment: That probably means something in the subsequent 2 commits caused a merge conflict.  Use `git mergetool` to fix the merge conflicts.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084483/what-should-i-do-when-git-revert-aborts-with-an-error-message

Comment: I'm in over my head. I ended up deleting the fix_reverts branch to start over. and typed:  git reset --hard master on the master branch but now when I do git status I have a bunch of these: .../huntday.js.BACKUP.12263.  .../huntday.js.BASE.12263.js etc. I don't want to track these files I am pretty sure

Comment: `git clean` to remove them.  `git config --global mergetool.keepBackup false` to keep them from being generated.